# How to change "Add new node" button label?

Tags: forms

I have created two content types "A" and "B".
I have included content type "B" in content type "A".
So when I am adding a content of type "A" that time it shows me a button "Add new node".
I want to change this label with another label.
Also when I click on this button it display form with fields of content type "B". This also shows a button with label "Create Node" and a title "ADD NEW NODE". I also want to replace with another string.
I have used `form_alter()` hook.

Can any one guide me how can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a small form_alter sample module code and start changing in it. Pl also see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx_aQpSQ5w0).

You can also do it easily using [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

Comment: I am new beginner in drupal Thank you for your reply but "String Overrides" not works for me. I have added a content type into a content type. I have checked after removing all cache.